# Appending the comments using AWK

Tags: awk

I am having a file having three fields id, name and location as shown below.

```
###Need to hold
078:james:US
###Need for version 3
946:wilson:UK
678:Joe:AUS
###Automate to rev1
456:Henry:UK
```

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk -F: /^[^#]/ {print $1}'
078 
946 
678
456
```

Desired Output:

```
078 - message "Need to hold"
946 - message "Need for version 3"
678 - message "Need for version 3"
456 - message "Automate to rev1"
```

I need to append the comment to the lines as shown above. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for single line comments

```
$ awk -F: '/^#/ {c=$0; sub(/#+/,"", c); next} 
                {print $1,"- message", "\"" c "\""}' file

078 - message "Need to hold"
946 - message "Need for version 3"
678 - message "Need for version 3"
456 - message "Automate to rev1"
```

for multiline support, you need to accumulate the comments.

*Explanation:* if the line starts with pound sign, remove the signs and save the line into variable `c` and skip to next line.  Print the first field delimited by `:` and the message label and finally quoted variable `c`.

Comment: thank you so much its working but I didn't understood the code which you have written. Can you please let me know

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I understood it.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
awk -F':' 'NF<3{h=$0;sub(/#*/,"",h);next}{printf "%s - message \"%s\"\n", $1,h}' file
078 - message "Need to hold"
946 - message "Need for version 3"
678 - message "Need for version 3"
456 - message "Automate to rev1"
```